How to check the running speed of each method in a Python class
I'm writing a python program containing a class. I want to find out the running speed of each method in my class because the overall running speed of my program is obviously lowered by my class. Is there any possible way to print out the running speed of each method cause I want to find the bottleneck of the computation.
I searched online and find a method called @decorator, but I don't know how to use it exactly. I think there must be other methods to do this.

Just blindly benchmarking all of your class methods is not a great way to go about finding bottlenecks. Instead you would run a profiler on your program, which would help with this task

"[...] because the overall running speed of my program is obviously lowered by my class" - what makes you say that? Did you compare the runtime to an implementation not using any custom class definitions?

Using a class certainly will not lower your performance. The class is not to blame here.

Thanks for all the help from stackoverflow repliers. I have solved this problem and I post my solution here in case somebody encounters the same problem.
import time
import functools

def timeit(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def timed(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time()
        print(f"Method {method.__name__} took {end_time - start_time:.4f} seconds")
        return result
    return timed

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @timeit
    def method1(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Method 1 executed")

    @timeit
    def method2(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Method 2 executed")
 
    @timeit
    def method3(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Method 3 executed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = MyClass()
    obj.method1()
    obj.method2()
    obj.method3()

`

timeit is the name of an important standard library and you probably want to use it as part of your solution

Using time.time() is not the best way to do this. I will post my thoughts as a new solution here sometime. Decorator idea is a good try, though.
